# opencv error: assertion failed in convert.cpp (opencv) when I calibrate a camera

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, windows-7, camera-calibration

I try to calibrate a camera (opencv 2.3.1, VS 2010 and Windows 7), but when I compile my program, there is an opencv error which is

> "Assertion Failed:<src.size==dst.size && src.channels<>dst.channels<>> in unknown function   , file ....modules \core\src\convert.cpp, line 1277".

here a part of code,

```
CvMat* image_points      = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,2,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* object_points     = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* point_counts      = cvCreateMat(n_boards,1,CV_32SC1);
CvMat* intrinsic_matrix  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* distortion_coeffs = cvCreateMat(4,1,CV_32FC1);

for ( int ig = 0; ig< n_boards; ig++ ) 
{ 
    
image= cvLoadImage(names[ig],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);  // load image

cvNamedWindow("imageessai", 1);
cvShowImage("imageessai", image);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvDestroyWindow("imageessai");

for (int ik=0; ik<n_boards; ik++)
            
{       
int found = cvFindChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners,        &corner_count,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS );
cvFindCornerSubPix(gray_image, corners, corner_count, cvSize(11,11),cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 0.1 ));
cvDrawChessboardCorners(image, board_sz, corners, corner_count, found); 
        
        if( corner_count == board_total ) 
        {
                
            step= ig*board_total;
            for( int i=step,j=0  ; j<board_total; j++, i++)
                        {
            
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*image_points, float,i,0) = corners[j].x;
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*image_points, float,i,1) = corners[j].y;
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points,float,i,0) = (float) j/board_w;
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points,float,i,1) = (float) (j%board_w);
        CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points,float,i,2)=0.0f;
                            }
                
        CV_MAT_ELEM (*point_counts, int,ig,0) = board_total;  
            
    printf("\n %d successful Snapshots out of %d collected.\n",ig+1,n_boards);
        
            }   
    } 

CvMat* object_points2  = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* image_points2   = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,2,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* point_counts2   = cvCreateMat(n_boards,1,CV_32SC1);

for(int i = 0; i<n_boards*board_total; ++i)
{
  CV_MAT_ELEM( *image_points2, float, i, 0) =CV_MAT_ELEM( *image_points, float, i, 0);
  CV_MAT_ELEM( *image_points2, float,i,1)  =CV_MAT_ELEM( *image_points, float, i, 1);
  CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points2, float, i, 0) = CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points, float, i,0) ;
  CV_MAT_ELEM( *object_points2, float, i, 1)= CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points, float, i,1) ;
  CV_MAT_ELEM( *object_points2, float, i, 2)= CV_MAT_ELEM(*object_points, float, i,2) ;
} 

for(int i=0; i<n_boards; ++i)
{ 
    CV_MAT_ELEM( *point_counts2, int, i, 0)=CV_MAT_ELEM(*point_counts,int,i,0);         
    
}
cvReleaseMat(&object_points);
cvReleaseMat(&image_points);
cvReleaseMat(&point_counts);


CV_MAT_ELEM( *intrinsic_matrix, float, 0, 0 ) = 1.0f;
CV_MAT_ELEM( *intrinsic_matrix, float, 1, 1 ) = 1.0f;
CvMat* rvec = cvCreateMat(n_boards,3,CV_32F);//matrice de rotation
CvMat* tvec = cvCreateMat(n_boards,3,CV_32F);//matrice de translation
CvMat* H = cvCreateMat(1,3,CV_32FC1);


cvCalibrateCamera2(object_points2, image_points2, point_counts2,  sizeim, intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs, rvec, tvec,0 );

cvFindHomography(object_points2,image_points2,H,0,3,NULL);
```

I tried to resolve this problem many times, please I need help.

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the line/method throwing the assert from. It seems you're passing an image of wrong type (wrong number of channels) to one of the cv functions. From your description it's hard to say but i guess it happens in cvCalibrateCamera2 or cvFindHomograpy.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm opening my comment as an answer since Nabiha might not be able to answer to a comment with 1 rep.)

It seems you're passing an image of wrong type (wrong number of channels) to one of the cv functions. From your description it's hard to say but i guess it happens in cvCalibrateCamera2 or cvFindHomograpy.

Assertion also sounds like a runtime error rather than a complie time error.

If it is a runtime error, you'd have to check if the Images you're passing to those functions have the correct setup (channels, same size etc..). This is something the compiler can't check for you since these parameters are dynamic.

You can methodically comment some of the functions (to debug your code) and see if your program still works, in case you have trouble finding out where exactly the code breaks with a debugger. Once you isolate the call, check the documentation on what it expects as parameters of your image and you should be on the right track to solve this.

Calibration is a multi-step process (grabbing images, extracting features, computing homography, computing the instrinic and extrinisic camera parameters). It is also tricky to understand (math-wise) so don't give up. The OpenCV calibration functions work usually pretty well.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i add a comment, then the error appears directly before cvCalibrateCamera2(),  the JPEG images (640*452) saved on computer disk are declared in the code :                 const char* names[15];
 names[0]= "calib1.jpg"; ....names[11]= "calib12.jpg";            then i  declare image= cvLoadImage(names[ig],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   it will be very interresting your answer

Comment: Still don't know if it's a compilation error or runtime error and which method throws it. Could you be more specific please.

Comment: it's a runtime error, the corners of chessboard are drawn, but the calibration is not successful;

Comment: my results:                     
    corners. [1] x = 364,498, corners [1]. y = 167.84
    image_points [1.0] = 0.0000, image_points [1.1] = 0.00000
    object_points [1.0] = 0.0000, object_points [1.1] = 0.00000
but the code is 
    CV_MAT_ELEM (* image_points, float, i, 0) = corners [i]. x;
   CV_MAT_ELEM (* image_points, float, i, 1) = corners [i]. Y
   CV_MAT_ELEM (* object_points, float, i, 0) = (float) j / board_w;
   CV_MAT_ELEM (* object_points, float, i, 1) = (float) (j board_w%);
how can i correct these results, please.

Comment: Does the calibration example work on your system (samples/cpp/calibration.cpp) ?

Comment: ok i corrected the error and  i got this result, <data>9.14172180e+002 0. 5.20431946e+002 0. 1.20339709e+003 4.96494873e+002 0. 0. 1.</data> 
please i don't have any idea if this result is logic or not,  it would be so kind if someone advise me or answer me .

Comment: If you ran the calibration over the example images this numbers probably represent the **intrinsic camera parameters** used as a basis for many other calculations you can do now. It's supposed to be a matrix in the form [ f_x, 0, c_x ; 0, f_y, c_y ; 0, 0, 1 ]. With f_x,y being the focal length of the camera lens and c_x, c_y the centers of the camera's sensor. Read the beginning of the documentation and look for **camera matrix** they mention: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

Comment: thank you for the quick response, now i'm trying to undistort image i got these errors:"assertion failed:( m1type == CV_16SC2 || m1type == CV_32FC1 || m1type == CV_32FC2 )" in unknown function, file imagproc\src\undistort.cpp; 
"assertion failed:(mapx0.data == mapx.data && mapy0.data == mapy.data
) in file undistort.cpp line 234
"assertion failed :( (map1.type() == CV_32FC2 && !map2.data) ||(map1.type() == CV_32FC1 && map2.type() == CV_32FC1) )in unkown fuction; file imagproc\src\imgwrap.cpp line 2534

Answer (score 0):

the debug button is not active and the rescan button ofthe solution project is not active, so I can not compile or debug the program samples \ cpp \ calibration.cpp

Comment: I would suggest you put lots of effort to get that example to work then since, once compiled and working it will demonstrate how to do the calibration on a set of example images. You will be able to refer to the example code and images.